# how can I get price cart from database in Code Igniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, controller, shopping-cart

it's my controller

```
function set_hargabesar($id){

    $this->load->library('cart');
        $condition['id'] = 'id';
        $get = $this->myigniter_model->getharga('harga_satuan','id');

        $data = array(
            'rowid'   => $id,
            'qty'     => 5,
            'price'   => $get,
        );

        $this->cart->update_all($data);

}
```

it's my model

```
public function getharga($harga, $id){


    $this->db->select($harga);
    $this->db->from('barang');
    $this->db->where('id',$id);



    $query=$this->db->get();

   }
```

How can I get a 'harga_satuan' (price cart) from database
please help me.

I can get the data(harga_satuan) from database with this code.

Answer (score 0):

You've only executed your query, you need to retrieve data.
Model:

```
public function getharga($harga, $id){
   $this->db->select($harga);
   $this->db->from('barang');
   $this->db->where('id',$id);

   $query=$this->db->get();
   $row = $query->row_array();
   return $row;
}
```

In your controller just change this:

```
'price'   => $get['harga_satuan'],
```

And, of course, you need to pass id to your model:

```
$get = $this->myigniter_model->getharga('harga_satuan', $id);
```

(but I hope you are doing it)

Comment: @gadis - have you done some debugging? What is in your $get variable? What $id are you passing in your model?

Comment: I want to show harga_satuan .from database where id_code = $id. but id_code in cart defined as rowid. And rowid is not id_code in database. How can i get id in cart = id in database

Comment: @gadis - like I said, you need to debug your code. I know, what **should** be in $id, but I am asking what is the value of $id on the page in the time it fails. And you didn't answer what is in your $get variable. My code is absolutely ok, you need to debug your inputs and outputs.

Comment: $id is a rowid in cart, and $get is variable to get some data from database, the data's name is harga_satuan

Comment: @gadis - I don't know, how to explain it to you. If you put `var_dump($id)` in your code, you probably get some integer or NULL. The same goes with `$get`. If you don't do debugging, we can't move further.